Problema de error en DataBase en Rails
estoy configurando rails en un equipo nuevo con linux, me corre rails y la base de datos, pero al hacer una migracion sale este error
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied for schema public
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" character varyin...
^
Caused by:
PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied for schema public
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" character varyin...
^
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
El Database.yml


el listado de base de datos seria este

No me deja emigrar ni crear la base de datos.
Como lo soluciono
Gracias
